# Написать функцию ToString, которая список своих разнотипных аргументов преобразует в строковой значение (std::string)

Tags: c++, строки, шаблоны-с++

Написать функцию ToString, которая список своих разнотипных аргументов преобразует в строковой значение (типа std::string). Длина списка произвольная. Например, для 
                          int n  = 17;
                       double x = 6.75;
                       ToString(“;”, 25, 3.7, n, x) ;

где “;” – разделитель между элементами, получим строковое значение “25;3.7;17;6.75”;

Есть такое решение, но оно почему-то не может работать больше чем с одной переменной типа double.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <utility>
 #include<string>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;
 std::string a, c;
 std::string x_first, c_v, mn;
 int i = 0,u;
 char* ch, *ch1, *ch2;
 template <class T>
 std::string x_f(T&&t)
 {
 i++;
 if (typeid(t) == typeid(char))
 {
    x_first += t;
 }
 else x_first += to_string(t);
 return x_first;
 }
 template <class T>
 std::string ToString(T&& t)
 {

 /*if (typeid(t) == typeid(char))
 {
    char x[] = { t };
    a += x;
 }
 else */
 a = to_string(t);
 /*a.clear();*/

 return a;
 }
 template <class T, class... Args>
 std::string ToString(T&& t, Args&&... args)
 {
 a.clear();
 if (i == 0)    c_v = x_f(t);
 std::string b = (string)ToString(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 if (typeid(t) == typeid(char))
  {
    c = t;
 }
 else c = to_string(t);
 ch1 = (char*)c.c_str();
 ch = (char *)b.c_str();
 ch2 = (char*)c_v.c_str();
 strcat(ch1, ch2);
 strcat(ch1, ch);
 //strcat(ch1, to_string(t).c_str());
 mn = ch1;
 return mn;
 };
 int main()
 {
 string my_x = ToString(';', 4.5,6.9, 8.4);
 auto h = [=](string x, string y) { return x.erase(0, 2 *  

 strlen(y.c_str())); };
 cout << h(my_x, x_first);

 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C++17 это можно будет сделать при помощи [*fold expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (выражения свертки):

```
template<typename... T>
std::string ToString(const T&... t) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  (ss << ... << t);
  return ss.str();
}
```

В C++11 это делается через разворачивание пака в инициализаторе временного массива:

```
template<typename... T>
std::string ToString(const T&... t) {
  std::stringstream ss;

  int temp[] = {((ss << t), 0)...};
  (void)temp;

  return ss.str();
}
```

В выражении `(ss << t), 0` используется оператор запятая, левая часть это сайд-эффект (запись в поток), правая часть - инициализатор элемента массива.

Вместо массива можно использовать список инициализации:

```
(void)std::initializer_list<int>{((ss << t), 0)...};
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например:

```
template <typename T>
string ToString(T t) { ostrstream os; os << t; return os.str(); }

template <typename T, typename ...P>
string ToString(T t, P... p)
{
    return [](auto a, auto b) { return ToString(a) + " " + ToString(b); }
           (t,ToString(p...));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ToString(2, 2.5, 'x', false, "rrr") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему, можете пометить его галочкой :)